# Pmf for winning $£10$ for each flip up to and including the first head

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A sponsor provides two prizes for a raffle. The first prize winner gets to choose a probability $p$ from $\left[\dfrac{1}{e},1-\dfrac{1}{e}\right]$. A sequence of independent coin flips with probability $p$ for a head are then made. The winner receives $£10$ for each flip up to and including the first head. The same coin is tossed in another independent sequence and the second prize winner receives $£5$ for each flip up to and including the first head in this sequence.

(i) Write down the p.m.f.s of the amounts of the two payments $U$ for the first prize and $V$ for the second prize.

I don't know how to write down the pmfs so that we can differentiate between the first and second prize winner.

Answer (score 1):

Since the distribution is discrete (only multiples of 10 or 5 are possible), we have:
$$f_U(n10)=P(\mbox{n-1 times tail followed by one time head})=p^{(n-1)}(1-p)$$
For the same reason is:
$$f_V(n5)=p^n*(1-p)$$
This question is highly related to the [geometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). In fact it is almost the same.

Since $E(U)=10\frac{1}{p}$ (use the mean of the geometric distribution to show this), we have that E(U) is maximal when p is minimal (1/e). Since U and V are independent (we toss again for the second winner), we have $E(U/V)=E(U)/E(V)=10\frac{1}{p}\frac{1}{5/p}=2$ and thus constant. This is intuitive because you would guess that the first person gets 2 times as much as the second person.

Comment: okay this is pretty much what I had actually, but then I need to maximise E(U) and E(U/V) and I'm not sure how to calculate those

Comment: I edited my answer to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Given $p$, and for $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$, what is the probability that the first player wins £$10n$? (each possible outcome for his reward being of that form).
In other terms, what is the probability that in the first sequence of $p$-biased coin tosses, the first $n-1$ tosses are tails, and the $n^\text{th}$ is head?